# How do I get started with Git Classroom with windows and rbenv?

Tags: windows, github, git-bash, rbenv

I would like to access to GitHub classroom to work on projects with others.

I have forked the https://github.com/education/classroom repository and cloned it into a local repository. To get started I need to run in my command line `script/bootstrap` (to get the requirements). However I have this error message:

```
"It looks like you don't have rbenv installed"
```

I tried to go run the command :

`rbenv-installer/bin/rbenv-installer` from Git Bash and I have this message:

```
warning: gcc not found; using CC=cc
aborted: compiler not found: cc
Optional bash extension failed to build, but things will still work normally.
/c/Users/Helene/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: line 1: ../libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

Then if I run :

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

I have this error message:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to make changes to GitHub Classroom itself, you can sign up at https://classroom.github.com/.